# Why doesn't this MySQL CASE query work?

Tags: mysql, case

I am a total newb and never used case before, so please don't laugh.

Why doesn't this query work?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `cronjob_reloaded` 
   WHERE `carid` LIKE '%bmw%'
      OR `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15'
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN `carid` LIKE '%bmw%' = 1 
       THEN 1 
  CASE WHEN `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15' = 2 
       THEN 2
```

I get this error:

> Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15' =2 THEN 2

Comment: Why doesn't work ? What are you expecting, and what do you get ? Please give us an example of data, desired output, and the output you're getting. And please, we don't laugh, we are here to help ;)

Comment: I have posted the mysql error just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a little strange. You don't need the `= 1` in the `LIKE` case, the second condition has an invalid `= 2`, and since both are conditions of the same statement, don't repeat `CASE` -- instead begin the second condition with `WHEN`.

It is also recommended to put in an `ELSE` case to match all other rows deterministically. Below, I inserted `ELSE 3`, which sorts all other non-matched rows after the two matching conditions.

Finally, the whole construct should end with an `END` keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM `cronjob_reloaded` 
WHERE 
`carid` LIKE '%bmw%'
OR 
`age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15'
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN `carid` LIKE '%bmw%' THEN 1  
    WHEN `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15'  THEN 2
    /* Advisable to add an ELSE condition to catch all other rows */
    ELSE 3
  END
```

Comment: I have added the END but its not working, so the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @webmasters Make sure yours looks like mine. There's more than just the `END`.

Comment: @webmasters Sorry I just noticed a spurious `= 2` in the second condition which I removed.

Comment: Now I get it:) you were a great help, ty!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two `CASE`. Just add single `CASE` like this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN `carid` LIKE '%bmw%' THEN 1
    WHEN `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15' THEN 2 
END
```

You have also wrote `carid LIKE '%bmw%' = 1` which is wrong. You should write `carid LIKE '%bmw%'`

Comment: what do you mean by `LIKE '%bmw%' = 1`?

Comment: @JohnWoo Oops! copied OP's Condition. I just updated the syntax of `CASE`. Thanks and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers don't need quotes, also you don't need `= 1` condition in `CASE WHEN` try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cronjob_reloaded
WHERE carid LIKE '%bmw%'
      OR age BETWEEN 10 AND 15
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN carid LIKE '%bmw%' THEN 1
               WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN 2
         END);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `cronjob_reloaded` 
WHERE 
`carid` LIKE '%bmw%' OR 
`age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15' ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN `carid` LIKE '%bmw%' = 1 THEN 1  
    WHEN `age` BETWEEN '10' AND '15' = 2 THEN 2
  END
```